# SQL - Pivot Column data to raw. Not as table header value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my current output format:

[image: PONO PODate Supplier ItemDesciption SPRorPR PR/SPR-No UnitCode UnitPrice TotalPrice O-1001 2019-11-29 ABC-Rox ABC-Item PR 21001 Kg 10 50.00 O-1001 2019-11-29 ABC-Rox ABC-Item PR 21002 Kg 10 50.00]

This is the output I need:

[image: PONO PODate Supplier ItemDesciption SPRorPR PR/SPR-No UnitCode UnitPrice TotalPrice O-1001 2019-11-29 ABC-Rox ABC-Item PR 21001/21002 Kg 10 50.00]

And here is my code

```
SELECT        
    tblPO.PONO, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), tblPO.POEnterdDate, 126) AS PODate, 
    tblSupplier.SupplierCode + '-' + tblSupplier.SupName AS SupplierName, 
    tblPOMaterials.MaterialCode + '-' + tblMaterial.MaterialDescription AS [Item Description], 
    tblPR.PRType AS [SPR or PR], 
    tblPOFromPR.PRNO AS [PR/SPR], 
    tblUnit.UnitCode, 
    tblPOMaterials.POQty AS Qty, 
    tblPOMaterials.UnitPrice, 
    tblPOMaterials.POQty * tblPOMaterials.UnitPrice AS [Total Price]
FROM
    tblPO 
INNER JOIN
    tblPOMaterials ON tblPO.PONO = tblPOMaterials.PONO 
INNER JOIN
    tblMaterial ON tblPOMaterials.MaterialCode = tblMaterial.MaterialCode 
INNER JOIN
    tblSupplier ON tblPO.POSupplierID = tblSupplier.SupplierID 
INNER JOIN
    tblPOFromPR ON tblPO.PONO = tblPOFromPR.PONO 
                AND tblPOMaterials.MaterialCode = tblPOFromPR.MaterialCode 
INNER JOIN
    tblUnit ON tblMaterial.UnitID = tblUnit.UnitID 
INNER JOIN
    tblPR ON tblPOFromPR.PRNO = tblPR.PRNO
WHERE
    (CONVERT(date, tblPO.PODate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) 
    AND (tblPO.POType <> 'Service') 
    AND (tblPO.POType = @Category)
ORDER BY 
    tblPO.PONO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using `Stuff` and `Distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblPO.PONO, CONVERT(CHAR(10), tblPO.POEnterdDate, 126) AS PODate, tblSupplier.SupplierCode + '-' + tblSupplier.SupName AS SupplierName, 
       tblPOMaterials.MaterialCode + '-' + tblMaterial.MaterialDescription AS [Item Description], tblPR.PRType AS [SPR or PR],  
       STUFF((
              SELECT '/' + CAST(T.PRNO AS VARCHAR(100))
              FROM dbo.tblPOFromPR T        
              WHERE tblPO.PONO = T.PONO AND tblPOMaterials.MaterialCode = T.MaterialCode         
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [PR/SPR], 
       tblUnit.UnitCode, tblPOMaterials.POQty AS Qty, tblPOMaterials.UnitPrice, 
       tblPOMaterials.POQty * tblPOMaterials.UnitPrice AS [Total Price]
FROM  tblPO INNER JOIN tblPOMaterials ON tblPO.PONO = tblPOMaterials.PONO 
INNER JOIN tblMaterial ON tblPOMaterials.MaterialCode = tblMaterial.MaterialCode 
INNER JOIN tblSupplier ON tblPO.POSupplierID = tblSupplier.SupplierID 
INNER JOIN tblPOFromPR ON tblPO.PONO = tblPOFromPR.PONO AND tblPOMaterials.MaterialCode = tblPOFromPR.MaterialCode 
INNER JOIN tblUnit ON tblMaterial.UnitID = tblUnit.UnitID 
INNER JOIN tblPR ON tblPOFromPR.PRNO = tblPR.PRNO
WHERE (CONVERT(date, tblPO.PODate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND (tblPO.POType <> 'Service') AND (tblPO.POType = @Category)
ORDER BY tblPO.PONO
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Vignesh Kumar A - it's working...... Thanks a lot for the support